# Xamarin templates missing in Visual Studio 2017 enterprise

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I had Visual Studio 2017 community before and Xamarin templates were there. I installed Visual Studio 2017 enterprise and now I do not see Xamarin templates like:

```
BlankApp(Xamarin.form Portable) and BlankApp(Native shared)
```

I have repaired Visual Studio and also updates but still same. Please advise how to fix it if anyone got same issue.

[image: New Project]

[image: Modify 01]

[image: Modify 02]

Comment: fyi: https://blog.xamarin.com/new-xamarin-android-ios-templates/

Answer (score 1):

There is some changes on VS 2017 15.6.4, click Mobile App(Xamarin.Forms), and click OK, A window will appear allowing you to choose a Share Project or a .NET Standard:
[image]

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/code-sharing#shared-projects) is about the Share Project, and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/code-sharing#net-standard-libraries) is about the .Net Standard.